# Can I save the output from a %sql block as an object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a %sql block where I on a data frame that I created with this code.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

I ran a number of queries to manipulate the data in a `%sql` block and I'd like to take that output and manipulate it outside of the block. Specifically, I'd like to bring it into a `%r` block and visualize the data. Can I make the data in the `%sql` block accessible from outside the block?

Comment: None of the answers good enough to accept, or at least upvote?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to write your SQL query as followed :

```sql
CREATE [OR REPLACE] [[GLOBAL] TEMPORARY] VIEW [db_name.]view_name
  [(col_name1 [COMMENT col_comment1], ...)]
  [COMMENT table_comment]
  [TBLPROPERTIES (key1=val1, key2=val2, ...)]
    AS select_statement
```

Example :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW temp_v
  AS SELECT * FROM db_name.df WHERE foo = 'bar';
```

Then you'll be able to fetch that into your code as followed :

```sql
val tmp = spark.sql("select * from temp_v limit 10")
tmp.show
// +---+---+
// | id|foo|
// +---+---+
// |500|bar|
// |501|bar|
// |502|bar|
// |503|bar|
// |504|bar|
// |505|bar|
// |506|bar|
// |507|bar|
// |508|bar|
// |509|bar|
// +---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on what @eliasah said, you could also keep all of your sql queries/manipulations in a `%spark` zeppelin paragraph using `spark.sql()` and skip the `%sql` paragraph altogether. This will give you a DataFrame as a result.

### From spark.apache.org/docs - sql programming guide:

> The sql function on a SparkSession enables applications to run SQL queries programmatically and returns the result as a DataFrame.

```
// Register the DataFrame as a SQL temporary view
df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
sqlDF.show()
// +----+-------+
// | age|   name|
// +----+-------+
// |null|Michael|
// |  30|   Andy|
// |  19| Justin|
// +----+-------+
```

And you can do longer, more complex SQL using triple quotes. Example:

```
val longerSqlDF = spark.sql("""
  WITH q1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM people
    WHERE age > 20 AND name like 'A%'
    ORDER BY age DESC
  )
  SELECT *
  , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY age) AS age_total
  FROM q1
""")
```